# Using Ruby MySQL Query fetch_row to count number of rows returns the previous value. Is there a cache or mem that must be cleared?

Tags: mysql, ruby

```
DB = Mysql.real_connect("localhost", "admin", "pass", "main")
number = 12345 #This number exists in table
#Create Date Entry
booking_exists = DB.query("SELECT count(*) FROM booking WHERE number='#{number}';").fetch_row

number = 12345 #This number does not exist in table
booking_exists = DB.query("SELECT count(*) FROM booking WHERE number='#{number}';").fetch_row
if booking_exists[0][0][0] > 0
  puts "Skipping Existing Booking #{number}"
end
```

So it counts amount of variable number that exists. The first one returns 1. The second one should return 0 but it also returns 1 unless I run the query again. I can't seem to find the reason searching for this. Is there some sort of flush query I'm supposed to do?

Thanks